# Laravel / Mongodb - How to get data based on array object key

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I have this array of objects in mongodb database:

```
"matching_competitors": [
    {
      "id_competitor": "19",
      "domain": "",
      "id_product_competitor": 35035,
      "url_product_competior": "https://www.bogas.ro/rochie-dama-scurta-catifea-neagra-antonietta-bogas/?utm_source=googlemerchantcenter&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=direct_link"
    }
  ]
```

Now, I want to get data where `id_competitor` is equal to 19. What I am doing is :

```
$get_product = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection( 'products_' . $id_project );

// another condtion.....

$get_product->orWhere( 'matching_competitors', '$elemMatch', [ 'id_competitor' => $match_to] );
```

Here the `$match_to` is contain **id_competitor** value.

But I can't get any result.